# What is the relationship between iproute2 and distro config files?

Tags: networking, centos6, rhel6, iproute2

For various ip manipulation activities, what is the difference/relationship between iproute2 and modifying the distro's config files?

For instance, some sources recommend `ip address del` for deleting an address on a network interface, and some sources recommend modifying `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` . Does iproute2 modify the distro's config files?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see ?

Comment: @Iain The primary question is whether these two methods are equivalent in their effects and whether they accomplish their effects in a similar manner. The modification of the same config files was simply one specific example.

Comment: The latter leads to enlightenment about the former.